# batch file to move file to another directory with time remaining

Tags: batch-file, time

i need batch file to move file to another directory with knowing the time remaining to finish the transfer of file in the batch file window

```
move /y %temp%\bigfile.exe d:\bigfile.exe
the file will transfer after:
```

((but if there is external file must be vbs or powershell but i need it to show the time remaining in the batch file window if there is no code in vbs and powershell no problem with exe file but give my example how to use it))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `bat/vbs` using the `Windows API`. This will display the time remaining to copy the file with a progress bar:

```
@echo off

set "$source=%temp%\bigfile.exe"
set "$destination=d:\"

if exist progress.vbs del progress.vbs
(echo Const ProgressBar = ^&H0^&
 echo strTargetFolder = "%$destination%"
echo Set objShell = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
 echo Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace^(strTargetFolder^)
echo objFolder.CopyHere "%$source%", ProgressBar) >Progress.vbs

call progress.vbs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the time when the file is copied:

```
move /y %temp%\bigfile.exe d:\bigfile.exe
Echo The file was transferred at: %time%
```

Comment: no i want to know what the time remaining to finish the  transfer of file to the d:\